# Choosing transformer for dual output forward switching converter

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm pretty new to power supply design, however I need to design a switching converter with the following outputs: 12V/6A and 6V/16A. I've read some notes and decided on forward configuration with some TOPswitch-GX as main controller. 
I'm currently reading the application note for designing forward converters based on these ICs: https://ac-dc.power.com/design-support/product-documents/application-notes/an-30-topswitch-gx-forward-design/

My current approach is to connect two secondary windings in stacked DC configuration mentioned in the application note. Since I need 6 and 12V, there should be the same number of turns for each one. The third secondary winding would be used as supply for the controller and feedback optocoupler.

The problem is, I don't exactly know where should I look for the transformer. I checked mouser, but I haven't seen any forward-dedicated transformers, and all the others was quite expensive.

I would like to know if my concept should be applied to that kind of converter. And if so, where can I look for standard forward trafos.

Regards,
Patryk

Comment: Typically a forward transformer is a custom-designed component.  You either design it yourself or work with a magnetics vendor to come up with a design that works in your application.  (If you are building enough units to justify their time.  If not you may have to buy some cores and wind the transformer yourself.)  You might get lucky by asking the controller vendor if they have a similar design that they did and if you can procure the same transformer.

Comment: No way to know if your design is appropriate, what's the input voltage? Do you need isolation? Do you have ripple and transient requirements?  If the input is AC, do you need universal input and/or power factor correction?

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I was thinking about PFC so the input would be about 400V DC. I have found a fendor in Poland which specifies in TOPswitch solutions. But I came to the conclusion that this SMPS may be too expensive for my design, and for now I'm considering regular 200W transformer with two low voltage switch converters.

The idea of HV converter was intriguing, but I think it might be too complex for me to make it work properly. Thanks for your time.